# Cucumber Scenario Outline with data tables - Capybara element not found

Tags: cucumber, capybara, scenarios

How do I write a scenario outline to test a calculation based on one variable which outputs 10 different variables?

I've tried various options and getting various errors including:

```
Unable to find option "<frequency>" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

and

```
(Cucumber::ArityMismatchError)
```

The code below gives the Capybara::ElementNotFound error

```
Scenario Outline:
  When  I select "<frequency>" frequency
  And   I press recalculate
  Then  I should see total amount and percentages recalculated by <frequency> frequency on the results page

Examples:
  | frequency |
  | weekly    |
  | daily     |

Examples:
  | tax   | sub-total | total  |
  | 38.25 | 114.74    | 191.24 |
  | 3.19  | 9.56      | 15.94  |
```

Step definitions

```
When(/^I select "([^"]*)" frequency$/) do |frequency|
  select "<frequency>", from: "frequency"
end

Then(/^I should see total amount and percentages recalculated by <frequency> frequency on the results page$/) do |table|
  expect(results_page).to have_content("<tax>")
  expect(results_page).to have_content("<sub_total>")
  expect(results_page).to have_content("<total>")
end
```

form markup

```
<form action="change_result_frequency" method="post">
  <label for="frequency">Frequency</label>
  <select name="frequency" id="frequency">
    <option value="yearly">yearly</option>
    <option value="monthly">monthly</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="weekly">weekly</option>
    <option value="daily">daily</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Recalculate">
</form>
```

I am new to cucumber and capybara so I'm unsure how to write scenario outlines with data tables. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is trying to write the detail about how your calculation works in your feature. Instead what you should be trying to do is use your feature to explain what you are doing (it has something to do with frequency, but otherwise I have no idea). When you take this approach you don't bother to specify the actual results in your scenarios for a number of reasons

1. The values of the results aren't that relevant to this sort of test.
2. Putting the results in the scenario is difficult, error prone (typos) and vastly increases maintenance costs

I'll explain point 1 a bit more.

What you should be doing in this scenario is driving the development of the change frequency functionality that you are working. This comprises of two parts

i) that you have a UI for the user to change the frequency, and that in response to this action your UI shows the results of the frequency change.

ii) that when you change the frequency the correct results are calculated

The first part, should be driven by a scenario in cucumber, so you can write something like

`Given ...
When I change the frequency
Then I should see a new set of results`

The second part SHOULD NOT be tested by writing scenarios in Cucumber. Instead you should be writing unit tests for the thing that does the frequency calculations. Writing unit tests allows you to

- write much faster tests
- write more tests so you can deal with edge cases
- write your tests in a programming language so you can easily generate and use values of any type

The biggest mistake I see new users to Cucumber make nowadays is to use scenario outlines and example tables. I'd recommend you stay away from them. Every time you want to use one stop and have a think. Ask the questions

1. What am I testing here and why is it important
2. Am I trying to prove that something works? If so shouldn't I be using unit tests for the proof.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You should only have one examples table with your Scenario Outline and you need to access the "variables" in the steps in your outline.  So something like the following (with your step definitions updated accordingly)

```
Scenario Outline:
  When  I select "<frequency>" frequency
  And   I press recalculate
  Then  I should see <tax>, <sub-total>, and <total> recalculated on the results page

Examples:
  | frequency |  tax   | sub-total | total  |
  | weekly    |  38.25 | 114.74    | 191.24 |
  | daily     |  3.19  | 9.56      | 15.94  |
```